# ADF not working on Brother scanner with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, scanner, brother

After installing the Brother scanner driver (brscan4-0.4.10-1.amd64.deb) for an MFC-J690DW, I could use the scanner with Simple Scan (Document Scanner) in single page mode but not with the ADF (Automatic Document Feeder).

I was able to fix this by running the following command in sudo mode (your IP address may be different):

`brsaneconfig4 -a name=MFC-J690DW ip=192.168.2.10`

After that, when I run the "brsaneconfig4 -q" command, I see the following:

```
scanimage -L
device `brother4:net1;dev0' is a Brother *MFC-J690DW 
device `escl:http://192.168.2.10:80' is a ESCL Brother MFC-J690DW flatbed scanner
```

Previously, I would only see the second line. In Document Scanner, when I select the "Brother *MFC-J690DW" instead of the "ESCL Brother MFC-J690DW" I can use the ADF.

Just thought this might help other users since I could not find this information on-line.

Comment: This is a Q&A site; where you've written your post as a Question; which is waiting for replies.  Thank you for trying to pass on your information so it helps others; but please amend your question with your problem you wanted solved; then write your own answer that solved it (ie. put the solution in the Answer section).\

Comment: This did also work for me with a Brother MFC-J6930DW printer.

Answer (score 1):

No really an answer but I need space to share my experience.

I had the same problem with MFC-L2750DW, firmware version 1.1 upgraded before seeing the problem.

I downloaded and installed the scan driver `brscan4-0.4.11-1` from Brother

```
% dpkg -l brscan4          
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  brscan4        0.4.11-1     amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
```

but this did not help.

Then I found your post and run

```
% brsaneconfig4 -q
  MFC-L2750DW  [  192.168.0.100]  Brother_MFC-L2750DW_series

% sudo brsaneconfig4 -a name=MFC-L2750DW ip=192.168.0.100
[sudo] password for : 
% brsaneconfig4 -q                                       
* *            [  192.168.0.100]  MFC-L2750DW
```

The output of `brsaneconfig4 -q` gained two stars and the feeder began to work normally.

Now I realize that all this is on [https://help.brother-usa.com](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/164930/%7E/install-the-scanner-driver-%28deb%29---linux).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had installed drivers using Brother's installation script, but select "N" when asked "Will you specify the Device URI?". Also, I did not at the time have the Brother (actually a MFCL2710DW, but the same probably applies) connected to USB.

I uninstalled, connected to USB and re-ran the installer. This time, I said "Y" to the question, then selected the option to specify IP address and entered the IP address of the Brother.

The script ran almost exactly the brsaneconfig4 command that Laurent suggested.

After that, I could unplug USB and both flatbed and ADF worked fine. I don't know which aspect of what I did is the more relevant, connecting USB or specifying the IP address.